# Normal user/token user authentication

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

In my Django project I need two type of users:
- users authenticated with login/password (django.contrib.auth.models.User)
- users authenticated with token (Django REST Framework)

What's more I wish I could keep both of them in one table and display only "User" page in admin panel.

What would you suggest will be the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

The token from DRF doesn't create a new User table it just creates a Token table with a one-to-one relationship with the existing User table, so you'll always have a single table (admin page) "User"

You decide what users should have a Token. for example:

```
# create API Token
regular_user = User.objects.create_user(....)

api_user = User.objects.create_user(...)
Token.objects.create(user=api_user)
```

now `regular_user` can only access using login/password (since he doesn't have a Token) and `api_user` can do both

Hope this helps